# Custom dojo widget won't clear text field upon button click

Tags: javascript, dojo

Upon clicking the clear button it pop up the alert and no show anything in this.gridQuery.value but the gridQuery input field itself doesn't reflect the change. Any idea?

```
define([
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    "dojo/request",
    "dijit/_WidgetBase",
    "dijit/_TemplatedMixin",
    "dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin"
], function(declare, request, _WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin){
    return declare([_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin], {
        //  set our template
        templateString: '<div>' +
        'Search: <div id="gridQuery" data-dojo-props="intermediateChanges: true" data-dojo-attach-event="onChange: search" data-dojo-attach-point="gridQuery" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TextBox"></div> ' +
        '<button data-dojo-attach-point="gridClear" data-dojo-attach-event="onclick: clear">Clear</button>' + 
        '<div data-dojo-attach-point="gridText"></div>' 
        + '</div>',

        clear: function() {         
            this.gridQuery.value = "";
            alert("Should be empty: " + this.gridQuery.value);
        },

        search: function() {
            this.gridText.innerHTML = this.gridQuery.value;
        },

        postCreate: function() {

        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not seeing any effect because you're not setting the value of the Dijit widget correctly.

Instead of:

```
this.gridQuery.value = '';
```

Try:

```
this.gridQuery.set('value', '');
```

Since there is no fully-cross-browser way of observing properties for changes,  Dijit's `get` and `set` APIs allow custom logic to be implemented around retrieval and modification of properties, and make it trivial to react to changes with `watch` as well.